# Animation Bounce Marker AGM Map

Tags: angular, google-maps

How to add Animation Bounce Marker in AGM Map Angular 2+?
Like this:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations
```

**PLUNKER:**

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this but it seems that the marker animation is rendered/initialized before the map is even defined.

Instead, what I do is:

```
<agm-map
  (mapReady)="mapReading()"
  [zoom]="14"
  [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lng"
></agm-map>
```

Then what this function does is simply:

```
  userLocationMarkerAnimation: string;

  mapReading() {
    this.userLocationMarkerAnimation = 'BOUNCE';
  }
```

And then on the marker, the binding:

```
  <agm-marker
    [animation]="userLocationMarkerAnimation"
    [latitude]="lat"
    [longitude]="lng"
  ></agm-marker>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! More explanation here: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1514#issuecomment-434136217

Answer (score 3):

From the library:

```
File: marker.d.ts

/**
 * Which animation to play when marker is added to a map.
 * This can be 'BOUNCE' or 'DROP'
 */
animation: 'BOUNCE' | 'DROP' | null;

So use:
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat"
            [longitude]="lat"
            [animation]="'BOUNCE'"
            [iconUrl]="'relPath-icon.png'">
</agm-marker>
```

Comment: I wish it worked. It just caused ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at MarkerManager.push../node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/marker-manager.js.MarkerManager.addMarker (marker-manager.js:72)
    at AgmMarker.push../node_modules/@agm/core/directives/marker.js.AgmMarker.ngOnChanges (marker.js:122)

Answer (score 1):

Just for info to everyone reading this.
Seems that all problems they had with animation are fixed.

Now there is no need for mapReady functions and stuff like that
You can put animation atribute directly on your marker, works as intended

```
[animation]="'BOUNCE'"
```

I use option to disable/enable animation on click

In your .ts file

```
bankina: string = 'BOUNCE'; //Set to null if you don't want it on start

bankinaAnimate(){
if (this.bankina !== null) {
  this.bankina = null;
} else {
  this.bankina = 'BOUNCE';
}}
```

And in your html file

```
<agm-marker
(markerClick)="bankinaAnimate()"
[animation]="bankina"
```